# How to find optimum column values when they affect another column value in time series data?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, python, inference, pandas

Original data frame spans a million rows and has an year's data. Here's top ten rows:

[image]

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': {0: '2020-12-08',
  1: '2020-12-08',
  2: '2020-12-08',
  3: '2020-12-08',
  4: '2020-12-08',
  5: '2020-12-08',
  6: '2020-12-08',
  7: '2020-12-08',
  8: '2020-12-08',
  9: '2020-12-08'},
 'points': {0: 200,
  1: 50,
  2: 0,
  3: 0,
  4: 150,
  5: 200,
  6: 200,
  7: 50,
  8: 100,
  9: 200},
 'count': {0: 19,
  1: 9,
  2: 32,
  3: 28,
  4: 22,
  5: 17,
  6: 22,
  7: 17,
  8: 28,
  9: 24}})
```

If you'd observe the actual whole dataset, you'd see that the 'count' decreases when 'points' is either too high or too low. How to find the optimum value of points? Optimum means the value of points that gives maximum number of counts. Answer might be a high school level mathematics solution.

One possible solution I can think of is to train an ML model using just points as X and count as y, (maybe no train test split), then make a data frame with points 1 to 500 and predict count for each point. Maybe the number of point with most count could be considered as optimum statistically?

Comment: Could you please define the meaning of "Optimum" over here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added details, by optimum I meant number of points that gives maximum number of counts.

Comment: It's hard to tell how you should model this with only this small sample. Can you add a scatter plot of all your data with y=count and x=points to your question?

Comment: @user2974951 They're anyway not making any sense. I've added a possible solution to the question at the end. Please see if that even makes any sense.

Comment: This does not make sense to me. Please add a plot of your data.